# Quando e onde apareceu "futebol"?

Tags: etimologia, ortografia, origem-histórica

Ando a ler a *Eternidade* de [Ferreira de Castro](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferreira_de_Castro#Obras), publicada em 1933, e o escritor ainda usa «foot-ball», com aspas e tudo (2ª edição, 1933, p. 25; grafia original; negrito meu):

> Mas a antiga capitania de Tristão Vaz, cenário dos amores lendários de Machim e onde a curiosidade lusíada primeiro fundeara, permitia ainda que Juvenal, recordando passos da adolescência, contemplasse a sua enseada garrida e a sua praia, na qual fôra aberto um campo de **«foot-ball»** [...]

O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) tem atestado em português *foot-boll* em 1889, *foot-ball* em 1899 e *futebol* em 1933. Mas frequentemente encontram-se ocorrências de palavras anteriores às indicadas no Houaiss.

Então eu queria várias coisas:

- Quais são as primeiras ocorrências de *futebol* em Portugal e no Brasil; isto é, gostaria de saber a data e publicação e se possível o excerto onde a palavra aparece. Se conseguirem documentar igualmente formas anteriores, *foot-boll*, fute-ball, etc., tanto melhor.
- Onde é que a forma aportuguesada apareceu primeiro. Será que já nessa altura havia aquela tendência que parece existir agora de os brasileiros terem maior preferência por adaptar a grafia enquanto os portugueses muitas vezes mantêm a grafia da língua de origem?
- A adaptação da grafia terá sido ideia nossa, ou terá sido inspirada em adaptações feitas anteriormente noutras línguas?

Comment: Para o espanhol *fútbol*, o N-gram viewer da Google [reporta](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=f%C3%BAtbol&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cf%C3%BAtbol%3B%2Cc0) o início do uso amplo da palavra nos anos 1920. Se a data 1933 do Houaiss for correta, a hipótese de uma influência do espanhol não fica descartada.

Comment: Sim, provavelmente, se o espanholamento for anterior ao aportuguesamento, "a hipótese [...] não pode ser descartada" é única coisa que se poderá afirmar. A data de 1933 do Houaiss está correta no sentido que eles têm a palavra documentada nesse ano; o dicionário não afirma conhecer a primeira ocorrência. Ele recorre sobretudo a obras de referência, dicionários e isso. Mas antes de aparecer numa dessas obras já teria na maioria dos casos aparecido em revista, livro ou  isso.

Comment: Interessante, eu não sabia que o Houaiss só considerava obras de referência - isso essencialmente garante que suas datas marcam a consolidação do uso, de forma alguma a primeira aparição. A questão do espanhol é quase um detalhe, por isso só coloquei como comentário. Além disso não sei julgar a força e rapidez da influência do espanhol sobre o português nesse época. Aproveitando: existe algum n-gram (e visualizador) fácil como o do Google para o português?

Comment: @stafusa, não diria que são só obras de referência; mas é sobretudo. Não conheço N-gram em português. Eu uso o google books, dois corpora e vários dicionários antigos, cujos links estão [nesta pergunta e resposta no meta](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288/resources-for-etymological-research-recursos-para-investiga%C3%A7%C3%A3o-etimol%C3%B3gica).

Comment: Tenho que me organizar melhor: fui checar a questão dos links e percebi que já tinha até upvoted tua resposta!